# How do I set up an external drive as a network share using the Raspbian GUI?

Tags: networking, usb, raspbian-buster

Using the GUI, **and only the GUI**, how can I share a USB drive on the network?  I'd prefer to use Samba since my clients will be Windows.  Using Raspbian Buster (current version) or later.

For reference, on Windows, it's as simple as right click, share, select users, and then it's done.

Comment: Why can't you use command line?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the command line.  Except that my experience with Linux and following random guides online using the command doesn't work, there might actually be a way to do it in the GUI that's ridiculously easy, and we have the GUI, so why not use it?

Comment: **SIMPLY**, you can write some scripts to do it. Sorry but your explanation is not convincing.

Comment: @M.Rostami Didn't realize that SE's had changed where I had to prove my explanation before I could ask a question.  Sad to see that this SE has gotten infected with SO-like behavior.

Comment: @YetAnotherRandomUser I'm sorry about that. Maybe you made some mistake, on SO, they are controlling and it's really significant. However, take note read the FAQ. Thanks.

Comment: You can't use **`only the GUI`**. Windows is absolutely irrelevant, and possibly why your question has been downvoted multiple times? Suggest you edit your question to eliminate the "only GUI" requirement - or just continue using Windows :)

Comment: Windows is 1,000% relevent.  All desktop users start with it, or are familiar with it.  The guy who does the yearly "Linux Sucks" show/convention has proof.  Something like 98% or more desktop usage (at the time; late 2010s) was on Windows.  Linux has been handed a silver platter since Windows 10 rolled out and squandered it.  best example is when the skinny Linus uninstalled his desktop while trying to install Steam.

Answer (score 1):

I had no trouble setting up my Pi 4 using Raspbian Buster as a NAS. I installed Samba and only had to manually edit a couple of text files to get a 2 TB USB drive shared. [This page](https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/articles/samba-file-server) at raspberrypi.org is what I used. Another possibility might be to use an OS specifically designed to run a NAS such as [OpenMediaVault](https://thepi.io/how-to-use-your-raspberry-pi-as-a-nas-box/).

Comment: OpenMediaVault is having issues at the moment, and there are no images with witch to install it.  I tried for a few hours yesterday, but didn't get anywhere.